# Does this procedure select an element uniformly at random from a ragged matrix?

Tags: probability, algorithms, sampling

Consider an $m \times L$ matrix. Each row $i$ contains $n_i \ge 0$ elements in the first $n_i$ cells (the following $L - n_i$ cells are empty) such that 
$\sum_{i} n_i = n.$

Here is a procedure that selects an element from among all $n$ elements:

- Choose an integer $i$ uniformly at random from $[1,m]$.
- Choose another integer $k$ uniformly at random from $[1,L]$.
- If $k > n_i$, we reject $i$ and $k$ and repeat this procedure;
  otherwise we return the $k$-th elment in the $i$-th row.

---

***My question is:***

Does this procedure select an element *uniformly at random* from among all $n$ elements?

Comment: One point to clarify, the number of non-empty cells in each row can be different. I.e., it could be the case that $n_i\neq n_j$ when $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. Every element has the same chance of being selected. The fact that empty cells are sometimes selected in between doesn't create any asymmetry among the occupied cells.

It can be rather inefficient though (depending on the occupancy) if you need to do this many times. If you have enough memory, you could write the coordinates of the occupied cells into an $n$-element array, choose a single uniformly random integer from $[1,n]$ and perform a single table lookup.

Alternatively, if you don't have that much memory, you can compute and store the partial sums $\sum_{i=1}^kn_i$, choose a single uniformly random integer from $[1,n]$ and perform a binary search in the partial sums to find the corresponding element.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't quite understand the "symmetry" argument. Is it possible to show that by calculation? That is, we aim to compute that for any element $x$, $\text{Pr}\{x \text{ is selected by this procedure}\} = \cdots = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @hengxin: In my view, your time would be much better invested in trying to understand the symmetry argument than in trying to calculate something here. I personally wouldn't know what to calculate. If you prefer, I'd be happy to delete this answer so that the question receives more attention and perhaps someone can provide you with the form of calculation that you seek.

Comment: A "symmetry" argument is absolutely OK (so please keep it). It is my job to understand it.

Comment: @hengxin: I'm using the term "(a)symmetry" here not in a geometrical sense but in the sense that the situation does not distinguish among the occupied cells, i.e. it is invariant under permutations of the occupied cells. The argument is that this symmetry is manifestly present after the initial selection (since every cell is by construction selected with the same probability), and that it is not broken by the rejection of empty cells, since this rejection also does not distinguish among the occupied cells, only between occupied and empty cells.